# How do I require('google-spreadsheet') in Ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been searching for a while for tutorials about how to import this module to angular2 - **Ionic2** to be specific - but without luck.

Is there any tutorial on how to implement this module to **ionic 2**?

I tried this but with no success(based on answer below):

```
let googlespreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
```

which produced the error:

```
Cannot find name 'require'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `google-spreadsheet` is not a Typescript module, you cannot import it into your Typescript file. You can, however, require it:

```
let googlespreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion above without success... this is now part of my code after some changes... http://plnkr.co/edit/veskMkWntoPx24w4r8uE with the error: "Cannot find name 'require'.at line 27 col 38" in my Atom text editor...

Comment: and then I tried this: import googlespreadsheet = require("google-spreadsheet"); and gave me this: Cannot find module 'google-spreadsheet'.at line 2 col 36

Comment: Something strange happened... Atom text editor has no complains but the CLI has `Cannot find name 'require'.` error on it...